# Dudas sobre mi proceso de normalización hasta 3FN ¿Podrían revisarlo y brindarme orientación?

Tags: mysql, sql, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

Estoy diseñando una base de datos, pero tengo dudas si he hecho bien el proceso de normalización hasta la tercera forma normal.

Además, no estoy seguro si algún punto específico de la base de datos se está generando algún tipo de redundancia

Consideraciones importante del negocio

- Es una sistema centralizado y se enfoca en la administración de
  sucursales, productos, pedidos(compra al proveedor), empleados,
  clientes, ventas.
- La sucursal central es el proveedor de los pedidos de las otras
  sucursales y se se presupone que siempre hay stock.Esto podría
  representar la entidad compra

Espero y alguien me pudiera corregir mis errores en cuanto al modelado de la base de datos y al la notación utilizada.

Si algo no queda claro, en mi explicación estaré al tanto para poder dar mas contexto del problema

Anexo los diagramas

**Diagrama Entidad-Relacional**
[image: Diagrama E-R]

**De entidad-relación a modelo relacional (sin Normalizar)**

[image: Diagrama E-R a Relacional]

**Modelo relacional (3FN)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan decir en que esta mal y poderlo corregir

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con **bien** normalizado? La base de datos está en su 3ra forma normal o no lo está. No existe una 3ra forma normal buena y otra mala. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal parece que tu duda es más teórica que práctica. Si es así, enfoca la pregunta a aquello que genera tus dudas sobra la normalización que planteas. Haz clic en [edit] y realiza los cambios correspondientes.

Comment: @MauricioContreras exactamente esa es su pregunta, si está (o no) en 3FN

Comment: A mi me interesa saber si este es un ejercicio teórico/académico o es un caso práctico real

Comment: es teorico/academico

Answer (score 0):

En la tabla `empleado` falta `idPersona`: entiendo que debe reflejarse igual que lo has hecho para la tabla `cliente`.

Respecto a las tablas `persona`, `empleado`, `usuario` y `cliente`: técnicamente están bien normalizadas, pero yo lo juntaría en una única tabla: persona: esto te simplifica enormemente el programa posterior, y técnicamente sigue siendo un modelo válido: simplemente se dejan a nulo algunos datos cuando no son necesarios.

Seguro que te han dicho que sólo puede salir un único modelo del proceso
de normalización, pero eso no es cierto. Si estás dispuesto a asumir que una persona será un empleado si el dato `numero_de_empleado` está a nulo, entonces podrán convivir ambas entidades en una única tabla de tu modelo, simplificando enormemente la aplicación resultante.
Me permito recordar aquí que un modelo entidad relacion **se hace para que la aplicación sea lo más eficiente posible**: si estamos complicando innecesariamente el trabajo con la misma, entonces la cosa va mal.

Veo heterogeneidad en los identificadores: `idEmpleado` es un `int` en la tabla `empleado`, pero es un `varchar(10)` en la tabla venta: mal, lo mires como lo mires. Te recomiendo que todos los identificadores sean un BIGINT y fuera problemas. Aunque las bases de datos permiten muchos tipos de datos, ciñete a unos pocos: `bigint` para los identificadores, `decimal(10,3)` para los datos económicos, float/double para las latitudes y longitudes, `varchar(250)` para los strings cortos, `varchar(1024)` para los medios y `mediumtext` para los mas grandes:
eso transmite una sensación de coherencia al modelo y evita que pensemos porqué ciudad es un `varchar(30)` y codigo postal es de 5. Han quedado ya muy lejos los tiempos en los que había que preocuparse por cada byte que se consumía en base de datos.

Las tablas `inventario` y `producto` están mal. Una sucursal trabajará con X productos, siempre, aunque hoy haya cero en el inventario. Cada producto tendrá su información de stock: stock mínimo, maximo, unidades disponibles, etc. Pero esta información (que tú representas
en la tabla inventario) debería estar junto con la información de la tabla `producto`,**a no ser que** cada producto tenga informacion específica. Por ejemplo, si tu producto son marcapasos, cada marcapasos tiene su propio número de serie, necesitas una tabla de productos para reflejar esa información. Si tu producto son compresas, cada paquete de compresas es indistinguible de otro paquete y no hace falta registrar individualmente cada uno.